# Android L -- EditText is broken

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop

Just installed "L" on my Nexus 7, and installed my app with a rather simple UI.

[image: An EditText and a Password EditText on Android 4.4.4]

Here is what it looks like on Android L

[image: The same UI on Android L]

Here is the relevant portion of the layout xml file.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/remote_control_password" android:hint="Enter a password" 
        android:text="" android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:password="true" android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Minimum password length = 4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/device_name" android:hint="Phone name (optional)" 
        android:text="" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="18sp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"/>
```

And this is the background drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#EAEAEA"/>
    <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp" android:topRightRadius="4dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="4dp" android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"/>
    <padding android:left="12dp" android:top="12dp" android:right="12dp" android:bottom="12dp"/>
</shape>
```

What could be going wrong?

PVS

Comment: Try temporarily removing the background drawable.

Comment: I can see similar behaviour on all _Views_ when _android:background_ is set to xml rectangle drawable - and _corners_ is used. Works ok if I remove _corners_ element - and if I don't - I see _"W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Invalid polygon 0x0, length is 0 @ isClockwise()"_ warnings on LogCat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround until Android L gets fixed (hopefully) you can try using

```
<corners android:radius="4dp" />
```

since your corner radius is same for all four corners. In my quick tests this problem seems to relate to using separate corner radius values. And applies to all View based classes I tried.

Also added report on https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=177